# How to completely fill a circle with a photo?

Tags: html, css

I want the avatar to fill the entire circle. it should be increased, but I do not know how.

Do `position: absolute` and remont, its position `left` `top`, but she's out of the circle.

```css
.photo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #f5f4f7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 17px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.photo img {
    -o-object-fit: contain;
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-position: 50% 50%;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bc/33/b5/bc33b5e3f3604819db0e4ca66a989c9e.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: try cover instead of contain

Comment: sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: here : object-fit: contain; .. use `cover` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simplified version:

```css
.photo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #f5f4f7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.photo img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /*center photo*/
    margin-top: 50%; /*vertically with these 2 lines*/
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bc/33/b5/bc33b5e3f3604819db0e4ca66a989c9e.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the image as a `background` as shown:

```css
.photo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #f5f4f7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 17px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bc/33/b5/bc33b5e3f3604819db0e4ca66a989c9e.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Remove `padding-top: 5px;` from `.photo`.

**2.** Remove everything from `.photo img` except height and width.

```css
.photo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #f5f4f7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.photo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bc/33/b5/bc33b5e3f3604819db0e4ca66a989c9e.jpg">
</div>
```